# How do I make a 2 column layout with a fixed header and footer in CSS?

Tags: css, html, menu, footer

I have been looking for tutorials on this for a while now and am coming across a problem.  I have a layout with a fixed header at 100px in height and a fixed footer at 50px in height.  In my content, I have a menu on the left at 200px wide and content on the right that fills the rest of the screen.  My header, footer and menu all have styles applied for background colours and borders.

What I want is for my footer to remain at the bottom of the window, or at the bottom of my content, if the content is longer.  I want for the menu to be the same height as the content, so that the styles I have applied will remain intact.  What I *get* is either the footer sticks to the bottom of the content because the content is shorter than the menu, or there is a gap between the bottom of the menu and the top of the footer.

Every tutorial I have found fixes this, ***but*** requires the menu to have no background (it takes the background styles from the `<body>` tag.  As I said, the styles I have applied are attached to the menu.  Is there a way to fix this?

**UPDATE:** My source can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/53SZd/3/.  That is what I have *now* (apologies if the floats cause all manner of headaches), but if there are ways to have it looking how I want, I am very open to suggestions.

**UPDATE 2:** I think my way of explaining this is wrong.  I have uploaded some images of what I want to my Google Drive that should explain what I want.

Whilst I do sincerely appreciate the help that I am getting here, there is always one caveat that appears.  Many thanks to Waz for his help, I do really appreciate it, but I am coming across one issue or another with each answer.  I never realised that getting the effect I want could be so hard -_-"

Comment: Your question looks dirty without your code, so please share it

Comment: Apologies, Mr Allen, added the source now: http://jsfiddle.net/53SZd/3/

Comment: You should check out ryan faits sticky footer, just google it

Comment: I have checked it out and that fixes the footer problem, but that still leaves open the menu issue.  But thank you for that, I am sure it will come in handy for another project.

Comment: be sure to mark the question as answered, so people don't come and give you more answers than you need and waste time

Comment: With regards to my update **What I want**

Menu longer than content: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3v7OTL2NkPmT2w3ZU9VelJvMVk/edit?usp=sharing 
Content longer than menu: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3v7OTL2NkPmMUprM0ZYeTdSTU0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: **What I am getting**

Menu longer than content: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3v7OTL2NkPmaUlWRko3Undxbmc/edit?usp=sharing 
Content longer than menu: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3v7OTL2NkPmd3RCU2lieXlnNXc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

seems that u might be using float property on the menu, if that is the case you would have to clear float with the footer or a div, but seeing the codes would be great help for your answer

Comment: Just added it now, James: http://jsfiddle.net/53SZd/3/.  There is a float on the menu, and there is a `clear: both;` above the footer, but that still leaves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it is to put a margin-left on your content of 220px (200 for the menu +20 for it not to be just aside the menu)

had the same problem, this solved it.

for the footer, the solution of james is the best ( put `clear : both` on your footer)

here is how it works : http://jsfiddle.net/53SZd/19/

EDIT : I understood the prolem was for the content.
 give your menu top= 111px(100 size of header, 11 for padding) and bottom=51px (50 height footer,1 border)   and your footer bottom=0px;

Comment: yes, that works too, because margin order is top/right/bottom/left

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in my browser (FF), because I still have my issues: My menu doesn't stretch across the  full length of the page, and my footer is still stuck half way up the page.

Comment: I apologise for the confusion there, Waz. That works fine with the positioning, but then I've got a new issue - The menu stays at that position and any content overflows outside of the menu.  I added a load of Lorem Ipsum text but I get this: http://jsfiddle.net/natehawkes/53SZd/17/

Comment: That works great on a long menu, but if the menu is short then I am back to my original problem.  I never realised that this would cause so many issues -_-"  I linked to images above that should hopefully betters show what I want.  And thank you so much for your patience.

Comment: hum, it IS an issue.

maibe by putting a div around the menu and the content, and making the them full size in height. I tried quickly on jsfiddle but nothing was good